# Get or set the console title in Linux and MacOSX with .NET Core

Tags: c#, linux, unix, console, .net-core

I am writing a console application in .NET Core 2.0 and would like to work with the console title by using the well-known `Console.Title` in Unix-based operating systems.

As I can see in the code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1be850f5708a820b132020cc9628efb972239db9/src/System.Console/src/System/Console.cs#L276), the .NET libs call two different methods for Linux and Windows for this specific property:

- [ConsolePal.Windows.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1be850f5708a820b132020cc9628efb972239db9/src/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Windows.cs#L610)
- [ConsolePal.Unix.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1be850f5708a820b132020cc9628efb972239db9/src/System.Console/src/System/ConsolePal.Unix.cs#L161)

And the latter throws `PlatformNotSupportedException` when getting the value of the title.

So my question is: **Would this ever be implemented for Unix systems and if not how to set the title of the console for Unix-based systems when using .NET Core?**

Comment: Note that you cant `get` the console title. You can still `set` it!

Comment: Getting the title is basically impossible in a standard way on *nix terminals. You can probably hack it for each terminal type (`xterm` has a title stack) but across different windowing toolkits (`gnome-terminal` vs `xterm` vs `konsole` vs `Terminal.App`), display servers (X11, Wayland, whatever macOS uses), it is probably easier to assume you will not have this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. You can promote your comment to an answer.