# How to get the window title of a process in C# on Linux/macOS?

Tags: c#, linux, macos

By default, GUI windows in Windows, Linux and macOS will show the title of the window on top of them and that is what I want to read programmatically with .NET Core 6.

On Windows, this can done by getting `Process.MainWindowTitle`. However, the documentation of that property states it will most often return an empty string on Unix system and so this what happens on Linux and macOS.

Is there a way to read this information on these systems? A native way to do so without dependencies would be preferred if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no by default functionality of .NET CORE in Unix

You can read the comment by omajid to get an idea

[Get or set the console title in Linux and MacOSX with .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059468/get-or-set-the-console-title-in-linux-and-macosx-with-net-core)